# Указатель на структуру в качестве параметра

Tags: windows, winapi, указатели, структуры, julia

Получаю время бесперебойной работы системы. Для этого использую `NtQuerySystemInformation` и структуру `SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION`, размер которой что в х86, что в х64 системах одинаков и равен 48 байтам. И вот здесь засада: как передать в качестве второго параметра `NtQuerySystemInformation` указатель на структуру? Я пока ничего не придумал кроме как сперва создать буфер фиксированного размера, а после реинтерпретировать его в структуру. Вот что я в итоге имею.

```
struct SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION
   BootTime::Int64
   CurrentTime::Int64
   TimeZoneBias::Int64
   TimeZoneId::UInt32
   Reserved::UInt32
   BootTimeBias::UInt64
   SleepTimeBias::UInt64
end

buff = zeros(UInt8, 48)
ntstatus = ccall((:NtQuerySystemInformation, "ntdll.dll"), stdcall, Int32,
   (UInt32, Ptr{UInt8}, UInt32, Ref{UInt32}), 3, buff, 48, C_NULL
)

if 0 == ntstatus
   sti = reinterpret(SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION, buff)
   delta = getfield.(sti, :CurrentTime)[1] - getfield.(sti, :BootTime)[1]
   ... # прочие вычисления
end
```

Понимаю, что такое решение вполне допустимо, но я более чем уверена, что правильней было бы сразу производить манипуляции со структурой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не могу сказать, что являюсь знатоком *Julia*, но все же: получить *uptime* системы можно простой командой `Sys.uptime()`, а чтобы привести полученное значение к простому для восприятия виду, придется станцевать математику:

```
x = Sys.uptime()
x = [(x / 86400), (x / 3600 % 24), (x % 3600 / 60), (x % 60)]
x = [lpad(repr(trunc(Int64, x[i])), 2, "0") for i = 1:length(x)]
println(replace(join(x, ":"), r"(\d+):(.+)" => s"\1.\2"))
```

Но вопрос был все же о структурах. В *Julia* как-то уж больно все с ними заморочено. Здесь скорее придется использовать `Ref`, то есть:

```
sti = Ref(SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

А вызов `NtQuerySystemInformation` будет таким:

```
nts = ccall((:NtQuerySystemInformation, "ntdll.dll"),
  stdcall, Int32,
  (UInt32, Ref{SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION}, UInt32, Ref{UInt32}),
  3, sti, sizeof(SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION), C_NULL
)
```

Ну и решение задачи целиком:

```
struct SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION
  BootTime::Int64
  CurrentTime::Int64
  TimeZoneBias::Int64
  TimeZoneId::UInt32
  Reserved::UInt32
  BootTimeBias::UInt64
  SleepTimeBias::UInt64
end

function get_last_error(ntstatus::Int32)
  err, buf = ccall((:RtlNtStatusToDosError, "ntdll.dll"),
    stdcall, UInt32, (Int32,), ntstatus
  ), zeros(UInt16, 256)
  len = ccall((:FormatMessageW, "kernel32.dll"),
    stdcall, UInt32,
    (UInt32, Ptr{Nothing}, UInt32, UInt32, Ptr{UInt16}, UInt32, Ptr{Nothing}),
    0x1000, C_NULL, err, 1024, buf, length(buf), C_NULL
  )
  print(0 != len ? transcode(String, buf[1:len]) : "Что-то пошло не так.\n")
end

function main()
  sti = Ref(SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
  nts = ccall((:NtQuerySystemInformation, "ntdll.dll"),
    stdcall, Int32,
    (UInt32, Ref{SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION}, UInt32, Ref{UInt32}),
    3, sti, sizeof(SYSTEM_TIMEOFDAY_INFORMATION), C_NULL
  )

  if 0 != nts
    get_last_error(nts)
    return
  end

  # дельту, наверное, лучше преобразовать в TIME_FIELDS c помощью RtlTimeToElapsedTimeFields
  delta = getfield.(sti, :CurrentTime) - getfield.(sti, :BootTime)
  # здесь же - исключетельно математика
  delta = delta / 1e7
  delta = [(delta / 86400), (delta / 3600 % 24), (delta % 3600 / 60), (delta % 60)]
  delta = [lpad(repr(trunc(Int64, delta[i])), 2, "0") for i = 1:length(delta)]
  println(replace(join(delta, ":"), r"(\d+):(.+)" => s"\1.\2"))
end

main()
```